# access token not get using gitlab api

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to authenticate my gitlab application with an user. I using gitlab api for authentication :-
'https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=4cf48a26d0c468c0c47c9ab73086d177f8618b269bc2500860672c5403c884f5&code_challenge=CODE_CHALLENGE&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000/api/gitlab-oauth-callback&response_type=code&scope=read_user+profile&state=123 `then I use this api to get authorization token :-`https://gitlab.com/oauth/redirect?code=${key}&state=123`.

My code example

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const clientId = '4cf48a26d0c468c0c47c9ab73086d177f8618b269bc2500860672c5403c884f5';
const clientSecret = '5240e8a9fb9305ce31a57be8c05b71e101b0574358c45e7831e07ccc0a2df9aa';
const https = require('https');
const { token } = require('morgan');
var request = require('request');
const User = require('../models/user.model')

exports.gitlabauthorizationprocess = async (req, res) => {

    const redirecturl = "http://localhost:4000/api/gitlab-oauth-callback"
    res.redirect(`https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=4cf48a26d0c468c0c47c9ab73086d177f8618b269bc2500860672c5403c884f5&code_challenge=CODE_CHALLENGE&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000/api/gitlab-oauth-callback&response_type=code&scope=read_user+profile&state=123`
    );
}


exports.getgitlabauthorizationdetails = async (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code
    key = code
    // const opts = { headers: { accept: 'application/json' } };
    axios.post(`https://gitlab.com/oauth/redirect?code=${key}&state=123`, {
        params: {
            client_id: clientId,
            client_secret: clientSecret,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4000/api/gitlab-oauth-callback',
            code: key
        }
    }).
        then(res => res.data['access_token']).
        then(_token => {
            let token = _token;
            console.log('My token:', token);
            const key = token;
        }).

        catch(err => res.status(500).json({ message: err.message }));
```

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code ...

Comment: @derpirscher I updated my code please help to resolve the issue

Comment: does it throw any error?